# Using LibreOffice instead of MS Office in Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp

Is it possible to customize Dynamics GP (using whichever customization Utility), so that it uses LibreOffice instead of the default MS OFFICE?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. Office integration is tightly coupled to the Dynamics GP product as well as many other Microsoft products.